# Arbitrary strings in bash throw python errors?

Tags: python, bash, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Something in my setup of my shell causes arbitrary strings like "krmpfl" or "u45g5svtJ7" to create a Python error:

```sh
$> krmpfl

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 28, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound import CommandNotFound
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py", line 19, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.db.db import SqliteDatabase
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/db.py", line 5, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
```

I would expect **bash** (and not python!) to throw an error of the kind "Unknown command krmpfl. Did you mean...", but any non-recognized command is for some reason passed to python. I am confused.

Does anyone have an idea on **how to debug** this or how to move forward? I've tried `type krmpfl` but this (correctly) echoes `bash: type: krmpfl: not found`

My setup:

- Win10 using Ubuntu 18.04 within WSL
- ConEmu as a console
- Bash-it
- Python 3.8
- Click (python package) installed to simplify creating commands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your current shell function defines a function named `command_not_found_handle`, `bash` runs that for a non-existent command rather than immediately failing with a "command not found" error. In your case, that function exists and calls `/usr/lib/command-not-found`, which appears to be a Python script that tries to download (or at least suggest you download) a package with `apt_pkg`, but you don't have that Python module installed, which leads to the Python exception.